# Cant get the Id from listview right

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

So I have an android app that has a listview populated by sqlite database, Im trying to get the id of an item when the button is click but it is outputting two numbers not one.
So instead of the answer being 5 its 5,1

Heres the method:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Id of Item: "+ myAdapter.choreslist.get(postion),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //choreapp.dbmanager.deleteOneItem(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What type of Data type do you use in ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get id from your model class like below code;

Call getId() method from your model class;

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Id of Item: "+ myAdapter.choreslist.get(postion).getId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //choreapp.dbmanager.deleteOneItem(i);
        }
    });
```